# How to pass queryparams in dialogflow CX using python

Tags: python, dialogflow-cx

I am using python and dialogflowcx v3beta1 library, I want to pass a query params to detect intent function but it shows an error.

I have read the doc: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1/QueryParameters but I am confusing with the format object Struct format.

How it should be pass in the code?

```
session_client = SessionsClient(client_options=client_options, credentials=credentials)
text_input = session.TextInput(text=message)
query_input = session.QueryInput(text=text_input, language_code=language_code)
query_params = {
        "parameters": {
            "param1": "value1"
        }
    }
request = session.DetectIntentRequest(
    session=session_path, query_input=query_input, query_params=query_params
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I used the next code.

```
text_input = session.TextInput(text=message)
query_input = session.QueryInput(text=text_input, language_code=language_code)
params = {
    "session_id": session_id
}
query_params = session.QueryParameters(parameters=params)
request = session.DetectIntentRequest(
    session=session_path, query_input=query_input, query_params=query_params
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a same concern with dialogflow nodejs api. Could you provide the JSON format data sample for queryParams? As QueryParameters obj can't be found in nodejs v3 sdk package.

[My realeated question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66326029/how-to-use-dialogflow-cx-api-pass-parameters-to-webhook-it-seemed-that-detectint)

```
var mapParameters = new Map([['Michael', 95], ['Bob', 75], ['Tracy', 85]]);

 const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    
    "queryInput": {
      
      "text": {
        "text": query,
      },
      languageCode,
    },

    'queryParams': {
      'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
      'parameters': {
        "fields":mapParameters
      }
    },

 };


const [response] = await client.detectIntent(request);
```

I also tried these, but did not work.

```
 const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    
    "queryInput": {
      
      "text": {
        "text": query,
      },
      languageCode,
    },

    'queryParams': {
      'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
      'parameters': {
       "p1":"p1 value"
      }
    },

 };
```