# How to use Dialogflow CX API pass parameters to webhook？It seemed that detectIntent() set session queryParams does not work

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

According to the google dialogflow cx document: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/QueryParameters

[click to show the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOhQJ.png)
I know we can use api to set session parameters. So I want pass the parameters to webhook by API way.

Step 1:Front-end, use detectintent() API, fill the queryParams item.
Step 2:Google dialogflow cx server will set parameters as the session parameter.
Step 3:Webhook receive the google-side fucnction call.We can found all of the session parameters from the http request.

As far as I am concerned, I can only receive the variables set in the DialogFlow Agent, but I have not received any parameters set via detectintent() API. I think I must have done something wrong, who can tell me how to? thanks.

My code as below(Nodejs code):

```
  const sessionPath = client.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
    projectId,
    location,
    agentId,
    sessionId
  );
 
  var mapParameters = new Map([['Michael', 95], ['Bob', 75], ['Tracy', 85]]);
 
 const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    
    "queryInput": {
      
      "text": {
        "text": query,
      },
      languageCode,
    },

    'queryParams': {
      'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
      'parameters': {
        "fields":mapParameters
      }
    },

 };
const [response] = await client.detectIntent(request);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem has been solved. It needs to be serialized/transformed.

So for the parameters' type mentioned in document, It need to be sent to DialogFlow As a "struct".

*Depending on your protocol or client library language, this is a map, associative array, symbol table, dictionary, or JSON object composed of a collection of (MapKey, MapValue) pairs:*

The right structure as bleow:

```
{
  session: 'projects/xxxxx...........',
  queryInput: {
    text: { text: 'hello world!' },
    languageCode: 'en'
  },
  queryParams: {
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
    parameters: {
      fields: {
        ID: { kind: 'numberValue', numberValue: 5 },
        Email: { kind: 'stringValue', stringValue: 'xxxxx@gmail.com' },
        Phone: { kind: 'stringValue', stringValue: '7789511xxx' },
        Domain: { kind: 'stringValue', stringValue: 'xxxxxx.com' }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pb-util](https://github.com/callmehiphop/pb-util#structencodejson) for encoding JSON object into [google.protobuf.Struct](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#struct) (as well as decoding the response).
You can pass the parameters in the detectIntent api in the following way:

```
const {struct} = require('pb-util');

const params = struct.encode({
  param1: param1Value,
  param2: param2Value
});

const request = {
  session: sessionPath,
  queryInput: {
    text: {
        text: query,
    },
    languageCode,
  },
  queryParams: {
    parameters: params
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try structuring your parameters like this:

```
{
  queryParams: {
    parameters: {
      fields: {
        Michael: {
          numberValue: 95
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow-cx/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3beta1.IQueryParameters.html)